# PHP Web Site with MSSQL Server Database

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection

When a php website can be opened using `xampp/wamp` on `localhost`, how can php file be open in the browser with a MSSQL Server Database? Can it also accessed using `localhost`. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can simply specify MSSQL connection settins in same way what you did with MySql. Before proceeding you check xampp/wampp if php_mssql extension is enabled or not in your php configuration.

example-

```
$server = 'server_address';
$user   = 'username';
$passwd = 'passwod';
$dbname = 'db_name';

$conn   = mssql_connect($server, $user, $passwd);
mssql_select_db($dbname, $conn);
```

Comment: How can I access the index.php? Do I still need to use localhost like when I am using the MySQL database? (Typing localhost in web browser and choosing the folder of the website)

Comment: Yes exactly, do in same way as that in with  MySQL.